# Android Media Player accuracy

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

i want to make kind of karaoke app, to do so i need to make ui changes at a particular moment (millisecond timing)

```
MediaPlayer.getDuration
```

is not the same depending on the device.

```
MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition
```

gives me millisecond but there is not precision (it will jump 200 millisecond one time 400 another and so on...)

so guys, how can i get the accuracy i want ? is there any audio player or audio player i can use in java ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically accuracy depend on:

1) how frequently you ask for `getCurrentPosition()`. In some cases I use 100 ms interval.

2) which media format do you use

3) and most critical depend on implementation.
Part of HW and SW related to multimedia vary from device to device and depend on device manufacturer, HW chips and OS version.

I suggest you to try query current position more frequently. And probably different media files.

Possible solution:

You can use software implementation of media player (ex: [FFMpeg](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ffmpeg.org%2F&ei=r359VMahJ6v6ywPixYC4Cg&usg=AFQjCNE0r3Wi1_Kpr9JhvUfDFBerSxTW1g&sig2=Kt-60Y6P_OtHuLCIK3lvPQ) can be compiled for Android). Negative side of this is CPU usage, battery drain and video decoding speed. Some devices cannot handle (too low fps) huge high quality video by without HW acceleration which is provided only by standard MediaPlayer API.

Comment: 1) i ask getCurrentPosition each millisecond (using a timer task) 
2) mp3
3) i use 3 different devices, same results on each device 
Thanks for your solution but i'm only using audio player, do you know other audio player (with better accuracy ?)
Thank you for your time.

Comment: FFMpeg can be also used for audio playback. But it's require compilation as native library.

Comment: what does that mean ? C++

Comment: Yes FFMpeg written in C/C++. You can also look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Comment: Does it necessary to use mp3 ? For PCM audio you can use AudioTrack class.

Comment: Yea i have seen it but what is a PCM Audio ? I did not get it. Just another sound format ? Will audio track more accurate ?

Comment: Yes PCM is audio format. More low level raw format. Unfortunately I don't exactly how accurate it is. PCM usually packed into WAV container https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV

Comment: ok thank you, i'll try to PCM then i'll use FFMeg (if it is not too much complicated) Thanks for your time.